# Spring 3.1 doesn't find css & js

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I don't understand very well because in my website application, js and css files are not found.
In the source code, the url goes to localhost:8080/dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css for example.

Here is the initializer :

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("resthub-mongodb", "resthub-web-server");
    String[] locations = { "classpath*:resthubContext.xml", "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" };
    appContext.setConfigLocations(locations);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");  
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
}
```

And the config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.resthub.dashboard")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
   resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
   return resolver;
}

}
```

And the applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.resthub.dashboard" />
    <mongo:repositories base-package="org.resthub.dashboard.repository" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Does anyone know how to do ?

Comment: problem solved

i have added 

        servletContext.getServletRegistration ("default").addMapping ("*.js", "*.css", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png");

in the initializer

Comment: You can add the default mapping in web.xml also

Comment: i'm not using a web.xml

Answer (score 2):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Need to be added in your *-servlet.xml for loading all the static resources. Please refer [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) explaining same.